# Reading and Writing to an NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

In my app I have a table view where the user presses an "add" button in the nav bar and a new cell is added to the table view. The data from the table is loaded from an NSArray and each index in the array is storing an NSMutableDictionary with 4 Key-Value pairs. This array is saved to a .plist every time a cell is added. Now when the user selects a row in the table a detail view gets loaded. This detail view simply loads the data from the saved .plist depending on what row was selected.

In this detail view I want to allow the user to edit the data in the dictionary for that specific row. I've been trying different things and I can read the data from the dictionary and load it into the view but when I try and save the data back to the dictionary my app keeps terminating.

Can someone explain to me the proper way to reading and writing data to a an NSMutableDictionary?

This is how i'm writing the data back to the .plist:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dict = [array objectAtIndex:selectedRow];

NSString *tempA = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d pts", ivar_A];
NSString *tempB = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d pts", ivar_B];
NSString *tempC = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d pts", ivar_C];

[dict setValue:tempA forKey:@"keyA"];
[dict setValue:tempB forKey:@"keyB"];
[dict setValue:tempC forKey:@"keyC"];

[tempA release];
[tempB release];
[tempC release];

[array insertObject:dict atIndex:selectedRow];

//Save the modified array back to the plist
[array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

[dict release];

[array release];
```

Comment: You can't edit the data in an NSDictionary directly, its immutable. Try NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: the data readed from PLIST should be inmutable, how do you modify the contents? and can you show more logs when your app crashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] dictionaryFromContentsOfFile:@"pathtofile.plist], the contents of the dictionary will still be immutable, even if the top level container is mutable. It is specifically stated in Apple's reference.

[NSDictionary Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithContentsOfFile%3a)

> The dictionary representation in the
>   file identified by path must contain
>   only property list objects (NSString,
>   NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray, or
>   NSDictionary objects). For more
>   details, see Property List Programming
>   Guide. The objects contained by this
>   dictionary are immutable, even if the
>   dictionary is mutable.

If you need to make the data structure writable again, you will need to make a copy of the loaded data structure using mutable types, like

```
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:oOrig]
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have been the problem because I got it working